# Is there a limit on Authorization header character length in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, http-headers, authorization

I am sending a GET request from an android app, AUTHORIZATION header  included.
When i check auth.password on the server  it is being truncated.
Original string 60 characters and the server is receiving 48 characters only.
Password is a hashed String

Below is the code for the function generating the request.

```
private String getToken(username, password){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // create HttpClient

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpGet= new HttpGet(url);

            String credentials= "";
            if (username.length != 0 && password.length != 0) ){
                credentials= username + ":"+ password
            }else {
                return "";
            }

            String encoding= Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes("utf-8"),Base64.DEFAULT);
            httpGet.setHeader(HttpHeaders.HOST,SERVER);
            httpGet.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encoding);

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

                result = new JSONObject(result).getString("token");
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            result= "";
        }

        return result;

    }
```

decoding the variable encoding back to string gives me the original credentials
`Log.e(TAG, "getToken: DECODED BYTES"+  new String(Base64.decode(encoding,0),"utf-8") );`

sending the same request from Postman does not truncate the password.

sample password `$2b$12$FywsqVzLrCR1iSVDLe7eBeK/.K07JUXX9YEHklyWPz9W7/nj52Xfa`

server Application is written in python

Comment: Would you mind adding to your question JAVA version? Also, the sum total size of all the headers in the request?

Comment: JAVA version  >>  openjdk version "1.8.0_202-release" .  I am not sure how to do that but my request doesn't have any other headers except the default + the AUTHORIZATION header

Comment: Gotcha. Since postman+JAVA seems to be doing the right thing for you, but android+JAVA doesn't... I suspect the problem isn't in the JAVA endpoint but in what your android app is sending. Can you post some of that code? Or is that what is already in your question?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this is to change this line of code
 `String encoding= Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes("utf-8"),Base64.DEFAULT);`

TO

`String encoding= Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes("utf-8"),Base64.URL_SAFE| Base64.NO_WRAP);`

This will protect the url against characters like ***' . '***  (dot), esp for encrypted password.
If you check the sample password, the dot character is there.